# UVA OnlineJudge 507 - Jill Rides Again wrong answer

Tags: algorithm

I've been doing [UVA OnlineJudge 507 - Jill Rides Again](https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&category=&problem=448&mosmsg=Submission%20received%20with%20ID%2015981694). I wrote the code and it works on every testcase from 'debug' page and form other forum.
But when I submitted to the online judge, it became wrong answer.
Here is my code

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int stop[30000];
    int n, m, i, j, ans, sum, imax, imin, tmin, a = 1;

    scanf("%d", &n);
    while (n--) {
        // get all values
        scanf("%d", &m);
        stop[0] = 0;
        for (i = 1; i < m; i++) scanf("%d",&stop[i]);

        sum = ans = imax = imin = tmin = 0;
        for (i = 1; i < m; i++) {
            sum += stop[i];
            if (sum > ans || (sum == ans && (i - tmin) > (imax - imin))) {
                ans = sum;
                imax = i;
                imin = tmin;
            }

            if (sum <= 0) {
                tmin = i;
                sum = 0;
            }
        }

        if (ans > 0) {
            printf("The nicest part of route %d is between stops %d and %d\n", a++, imin + 1, imax + 1);
        } else {
            printf("Route %d has no nice parts\n", a++);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: 1) `int stop[30000];` could be a bit large for automatic storage. Suggest moving it to global. 2) `#include <cstdio>` wont work on a true C compiler.

Comment: Please don't put 'Solved' in your title - instead you should indicate that your question has been satisfactorily answered by selecting the check mark beside the appropriate answer.

Comment: ... and please give credit where credit is due ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're breaking the bicycle ride when sum of niceness is equal to 0 at the stop `i`, so you'll miss longer solution with the same sum, if the route with maximal possible niceness starts at the stop `i`.

I've changed condition `if (sum <= 0)` to `if (sum < 0)` and solution have passed all tests.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, line `if (sum <= 0) {` should read `if (sum < 0) {`. The reason is that that way you don't reset the longest non-negative subsequence that ends in position `i`.

Your algorithm is esentially Kadane's Algorithm. I made a [graphical explanation](http://ruslanledesma.com/2016/03/05/jill-rides-again.html) of why you should change the condition in line `if (sum <= 0) {` and of Kadane's Algorithm in general, which could help you understand the reason.